# Single Database and Many Users Desktop Application

Tags: c#, database, web-services, client-server, data-synchronization

I am new to this concept so i need guidance that what will be best to use in following scenario.

I have to make a desktop application that contains many features like `parts Stock` ,`Employees Data`,`Company Cars Data` etc etc.

now the problem is that many users would be using the application and offices situated are in different cities in which this application is installed.

I want a scheme that if one uploads any data to database other gets its reflection and other instantly gets updated.for example if more cars are added everyone using gets their cars list updated.

I was having idea to use `webservices` and data should be stored somewhere on website database so that everyone's application refreshes lists every say 20 seconds or so.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: [Client server architecture ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model)this might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't reload all your data constantly; there are a couple of common approaches here:

- keep a list of *changes*; if you add new data you add the primary data record *and* you write the fact that the change happened (essentially an "events" list). Then you can query the change log periodically to get and additions/updates/deletes simply by asking for all events after (x)
- if the infrastructure allows, some kind of pub/sub framework - same approach really but typically using middleware for the changes, rather than the main DB

re how you get the data; polling is simple and effective; active pushing is harder to setup but may reduce latency - not sure it is worth it here

Another approach, though, is to design it as a web app - then all your data lives at the server-farm and is trivial to update immediately. Your "desktop" app could be a web page using ajax

Comment: so can web services do the job? and like every hosting has database is it possible it use webservices to populate that database on website and use it later?

Refreshing Point is great never thought of it

Comment: @Lagrangian do you mean "can web services be used to query for data periodically?" absolutely! It is easier to setup webservices for "pull" (polling) than "push", though - so do that. You just need a "get me the recent changes that affect me" web-service method

Answer (score 2):

Try Cloud Computing and store your data into cloud

OK trying to recover my points here after the downvote.

The cloud (windows Azure especially) is a great fit for this project.  Web services would help too as they can be easily scaled out to a number of webservers (Instances in Azure speak).  Having many desktop clients talking directly to a database is not a good idea and often results in scalability issues.

Output cacheing could help a great deal here if you are refreshing your client side data frequently, this can be implemented with almost no code.  This makes it much easier to do than managing lists of changes.

Comment: -1 for not going into any detail either on how to do that, or why it would be a good way to solve his problem.

Comment: @Irvin +1 for listening.  Try to give more details first time around next time.